# How to set a row height in a export from Laravel Excel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export, laravel-excel

It's possible to auto size the columns but is there a way set the row size automaticaly?

I've searched for it in the oficial docs and didn't found anything for the 3.1 version.

I've also tried the issue on the project's GitHub page, but they instruct you to search help on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late to give an answer. But if you or maybe someone else still needs it, I have a solution using PhpOffice~

First, call the Spreadsheet from PhpOffice

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
```

then

```php
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$rowDimension = 2; // <- Row Number
$rowHeight = 40;   // <- row height

$sheet->getRowDimension($rowDimension)
      ->setRowHeight($rowHeight);
```

You can learn more about basic alignment in [their github repository](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/7e3807309de6794fb277ceb8ef9af8bb6969e775/samples/Basic/49_alignment.php)